# Conditioned MICE imputation / with restrictions

Tags: r, database, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset like this:

```
d <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0),
                X2 = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0))

  X1 X2
1  1 NA
2  1  0
3 NA NA
4 NA NA
5  0  0
6 NA NA
7 NA NA
8  1  1
9  0  0
```

I want to perform `mice` imputation with the following condition based on the future imputed values of X1:

- If X1 = 0 --> X2 = 0
- If X1 = 1 --> X2 = 0 or 1

How can I write this condition? The base code for my imputation is:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(d, seed=123, m=5, maxit=10)
```

I am having troubles in understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a [passive imputation approach as described by Heymans and Eekhout (2019)](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/missing-data-in-questionnaires.html) by specifying the imputation method. If `X1` is 0, `X2` will always be 0, but if `X1` is `1`, then the usual `pmm` method (or whatever method you specify) applies.

```
library(mice)
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0),
                X2 = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0))

fakeimp <- mice(d, seed = 123, maxit = 0, printFlag = FALSE)
meth <- fakeimp$method
meth["X2"] <- "~I((ifelse(X1 == 0, 0, X2)))"

imp <- mice(d, seed = 123, m = 5, maxit = 10, method = meth, printFlag = FALSE)

full <- complete(imp, action = "long", include = FALSE)
head(full)
#>   .imp .id X1 X2
#> 1    1   1  1  1
#> 2    1   2  1  0
#> 3    1   3  1  0
#> 4    1   4  0  0
#> 5    1   5  0  0
#> 6    1   6  0  0
```